# Use asynchronous function inside _.map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, lodash

I am using lodash library for iteration. I have used _.map() function for this purpose. I have a problem that I have an asynchronous function inside _.map(). My code is like this:

```
 let dataToRender = {};
 let modifiedData = _.map(myArray, (element) => {
      dataToRender.uuid = element.UID;
      dataToRender.pendingAmountReceived = element.$.SR;
      dataToRender.orderID = element.TransactionID;
      dataToRender.orderAmount = element.TransactionValue;
      dataToRender.orderDate = moment(element.TransactionTime, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
      dataToRender.goal = element.Product.replace('amp;', '&');
      dataToRender.currentStatus = 'waiting';

      //Here CheckFilter is my asynchrounous function
      //I have to do calculation base on the response of this checkFilter

      checkFilter(requireParams)
        .then(data => {
          //If the response returned from checkFilter is false I have to include this data
          if (!data) {
            return requireParams;
          }
        });
    });
 res.json(modifiedData);
```

But I am getting just null in modifiedData. How to get all the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) provides a number of promise helper methods including [`Promise.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) which will only resolve when all returned promises are resolved.

The only problem is you will end up with `undefined` values in your results for when the `checkFilter` function is truthey. lodash's [`_.compact`](https://lodash.com/docs#compact) function can help here or you can use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) if you have more specific filtering needs.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
let dataToRender = {};
Promise.map(myArray, element => {
  dataToRender.uuid = element.UID;
  dataToRender.pendingAmountReceived = element.$.SR;
  dataToRender.orderID = element.TransactionID;
  dataToRender.orderAmount = element.TransactionValue;
  dataToRender.orderDate = moment(element.TransactionTime, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
  dataToRender.goal = element.Product.replace('amp;', '&');
  dataToRender.currentStatus = 'waiting';

  return checkFilter(requireParams)
    .then(data => {
      // If the response returned from checkFilter is false I have to include this data
      if (!data) return requireParams;
    });
})
.then(results => res.json(_.compact(results)) );
```

Comment: Ahhh, thats made my day